# How to subscribe event by using nvim_subscribe

Tags: neovim

I am trying to handle events of nvim using nvim_subscribe() API via RPC. For instance, calling nvim_subscribe('CmdLineEnter').

I am not sure the specification of this API exactly, but I imagine that the notification will be call back to the client when the 'CmdLineEnter' event occurs in nvim.
Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to subscribe to events.

First monitor the event you want to subscribe with autocmd, and emit the event I defined myself by using rpcnotify().
For instance, define an autocmd in init.vim as below:

```
autocmd CmdLineEnter * call rpcnotify(0, 'mymethod')
```

Or define it by nvim_command(`above autocmd`) via RPC.

Then, after execute `nvim_subscribe('mymethod')`, nvim notifies `mymethod` event to the client via RPC whenever CmdLineEnter event happens.

Comment: What does `nvim_subscribe` do in this case / why do you need to invoke it? Shouldn't you just get the notification from `rpcnotify` without it when the `CmdLineEnter` autocmd is triggered?

Comment: I did some digging here. If you rpcnotify a specific channel, subscriptions do not matter. If you rpcnotify with channel 0 (broadcast), only channels that have subscribed to the event will receive it.